# Selendroid ANDROID_HOME path issue in MAC machine eclipse IDE

Tags: android, macos, selendroid

I'm using MAC maverics OS. 
Installed Android sdk through android studio and set Android_home and path through bash profile.
when I type following command , I can see the home path in the terminal

$ echo $ANDROID_HOME
/Users/balaji/Library/Android/sdk

When I try to launch the script from Eclipse , I get error as 
Error building server: io.selendroid.server.common.exceptions.SelendroidException: Environment variable 'ANDROID_HOME' was not found!

Can any one help me out?

Comment: Refer to my answer here.[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29688884/error-when-i-try-to-execute-selendroid-command/29742865#29742865][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29688884/error-when-i-try-to-execute-selendroid-command/29742865#29742865

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue.

Please try to set `ANDROID_HOME` as an environment variable in eclipse.
This is how it's done:

1. select the class you wanna run
2. right click on it
3. go to: run as -> run configurations -> environment
4. here you can add the variable `ANDROID_HOME` with the path to your android sdk

I hope it will help you solve your issue.